# firebase retrieve complex structure

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I am new to Firebase database. Currently I am developing a android application. I am looking for a help, Below is my Firabase Data Structure. Can anyonce please tell me how to retrive the data.

Requirement is I have to retrieve the all the companies. Upon selecting the a specific company, it has to fetch the corresponding company coordinates into polygon shape variable.

Please Help

[image]

Comment: It's better if you can explain with some example.

Comment: in my application I have to retrieve the all the companies(Amazon, Google..)and place these companies into ListView or some drop down if i select any company then it should fetch me the coordinates for the slected company 

.....in other words...Step one is extract the companies. step 2 is retrieving the coordinates

Comment: You are having company under some ID do one ID can have more than one country or only single one is allowed

Comment: each ID will have single company

Comment: If you can change the structure of your database it will be better as ID should be child of company and top level object should contain the array of company instead of ID's. But if you want to go with current structure then refer the below answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a structure like:

companyName/info

Instead of

Firebase ID/Companyname/info

i.e use update or set instead of push

Comment: Thanks Nikhil Now i can save the companies without the firebase IDs.But can you tell me how to list the companies into array

Comment: I think you should update your question to reflect your complete requirements. You should first decide on what you want to query and then design the structure according to that.Also, if the suggested approach resolves your problem, please mark that as the answer. You can , of course, continue to ask questions in the thread.

Comment: Sorry for making confusion here. I updated my structure in query. Now can you please tell me how to retrieve the data from each layer in to one object. I mean in the diagram what class structure should i  use inorder to fetch all the data values from one onbject. (And structure of first object is same for all the objects.)

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. Looking at your original question. if all you want is drop down list of companies and upon selecting one, you want to fetch the lat-long. Your structure could be  Root/Companies/Company1/Co-ordinate, Root/Companies/Company2/Co-ordinate  . Upon selecting a company just access /Root/Companies/<Selected company name dropdownvalue>/ Co-ordinate. There is no need to query.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CompanyIds{
   public List<Company> companies;
}


FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("parent node path of these ID's");
```

Now in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter what you can do is:-

```
@Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(final MessagesHolder viewHolder, CompanyIds model, int position) {
        Company = model.companies.get(0);
        //Set data on your view from Company model
    }
```

As your ID is having only one company then you get that only company from the first index.

Now after clicking on any item, you can easily get the details for a company like coordinates or anything else in the same way you set the data in the adapter. It won't be a problem.

```
public class Company{
       List<String> Cordinates;
       List<Employees> Employees;
       //Define other fields
}
```

Comment: Thanks Avi. As you suggested i can save the companies without ID but now  can you tell me how to retrieve the companies and then coordinates

Comment: You can keep the same structure of your company object as it is in database.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I got the answer from repetitive hits and tries while working on the similar problem.

Look when you go for general approach of add addValueEventListner(), you get a snapshot of the database with respect to your root node. Thus on the first addValueListner() callback, get the reference of your child node and then addChildEventListner() on it. So here is what i suggest:

```
 DatabaseReference databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

 databaseReference.addValueEventListner(new ValueEventListner(){
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
```

//here your snapshot is considered with respect to root. So you get the reference of child node now

```
 datasnapshot.child("Bureau 507").getRef().addChildEventListner(new 
 ChildEventListner){
  @Override
 public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s){
  for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
  //Now you are at the subtree of Bureua 507. So now you get your data in the form of 
  key and values
  } 

//remaining callbacks
```